# late-bound stored procedure execution with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm looking for a way to do something like this:

```
var  db = new DALEntities();
db.StoredProcedureToCall();
```

but, I want it to be dynamic, in that I won't know WHICH call to make until after some other data is delivered to me.

```
var db = new DALEntities();
db[tSproc]();
```

I know I could have a switch statement test the value of tSproc, and then call as above, but is there a more elegant way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your cursor on `db.StoredProcedureToCall()` and press F12. You'll see the code that EF generated is already dynamic.

Depending on the EF version you use, it will look something like:

```
public ObjectResult<OrderDetail> GetDetailsForOrder
 (Nullable<global::System.Int32> orderid)
{
  ObjectParameter orderidParameter;
  if (orderid.HasValue)
  {
    orderidParameter = new ObjectParameter("orderid", orderid);
  }
  else
  {
    orderidParameter = new ObjectParameter("orderid", typeof(global::System.Int32));
  }
  return base.ExecuteFunction<OrderDetail>("GetDetailsForOrder", orderidParameter);
}
```

Just write your code similarly. You don't need a switch.

Comment: excellent, thats exactly what I needed...though, from the look of it, and moreover, now that I __THINK__ of it, I expect I will still need the switch, because I'll have variable numbers of parameters to deal with.